# What are the directions generated by the Newton method for $f(Ay)$?

Tags: optimization, newton-raphson

Suppose $A \in R^{n \times n}$ and that $A$ is invertible, derive the directions generated by the Newton Method for the following problem

$\min_{y \in R^n} f(Ay)$

I know what it means now but am stuck. I think I have found the gradient but am stuck with the Hessian. Gradient should be $\nabla f(Ay)^T A$ but what about the Hessian?

Comment: I assume you meant $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$.

Comment: Yes, this is fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g(y) = f(Ay)$. The Newton direction is $\Delta x = -H_g(y)^{-1} D_g(y)$. By application of the chain rule, $D_g(y) = A^TD_f(Ay)$ and $H_g(y) = A^TH_f(Ay)A$, so

$$\Delta x = -(A^TH_f(Ay)A)^{-1} (A^TD_f(Ay))=-A^{-1}H_f(Ay)^{-1}D_f(Ay).$$

Comment: Dimensionality of the Hessian is $n \times n$?

Comment: @InvestingScientist yes, element $(i,j)$ is the second derivative with respect to $y_i$ and $y_j$.

Comment: How did you get the final equality?

Comment: What did you rearrange/cancel to get it into that form?

Comment: @InvestingScientist $(ABC)^{-1} = C^{-1}B^{-1}A^{-1}$, and $(A^T)^{-1}$ cancels with $A^T$

Comment: Thanks, Completely forgot the first identity